# Any way to control webcam exposure in opencv using java?

Tags: java, opencv

I need to control my webcameras exposure in openCV. I can't seem to figure out how to do it and whether it is possible or not.

Comment: What did you try so far ? Can we see some code ? Please take some time to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean by "exposure"? There isn't any film in a webcam.

Comment: By exposure, I mean exposure http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/camera-exposure.htm.

What I have tried so far is to find how to get CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE to work in Java (with no luck so far).